# Load CSS file from assets to a WebView with custom HTML and predefined Base URL

Tags: android, html, css, webview

I need to load some HTML that I construct at runtime into a WebView and **apply a CSS file** to it **placed in the assets directory**. And I **already have a base URL** that I need to provide to the webview's `loadDataWithBaseURL` function.

Code Snippet (not applying CSS file):

```
StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
buff.append("<head>");
buff.append("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"file:///android_asset/my_css_file.css\"/>");
buff.append("</head>");
buff.append("<div class=\"announcement-header\">");
buff.append("HEADER");
buff.append("</div>");
buff.append("<div class=\"announcement-separator\"></div>");
buff.append("<div class=\"announcement\">");
buff.append("CONTENT");
buff.append("</div>")
WebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(MY_BASE_URL, buff.toString(), "text/html", HTTP.UTF_8, null);
```

I've looked at these 2 similar issues [Issue 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31516518/how-to-load-android-assets-css-files-to-android-webview-url) & [Issue 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585210/webview-add-local-css-file-to-an-html-page), but my case is slightly different as I cant give `file:///android_asset/` as the base url to the `loadDataWithBaseURL` function.

Any ideas how I can apply the CSS file in this case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to intercept some of the requests from `WebView` you can do so by overriding `shouldInterceptRequest()` in `WebViewClient` like this:

```
 public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest (final WebView view, String url) {
        if (URLUtil.isFileUrl(url) && url.contains(".css")) {
            return getCssWebResourceResponseFromAsset();
        } else {
            return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
        }
    }
```

There is already an excellent detailed answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/8274881/1112882

**HOWEVER**
You can not access local file if your base url is not local because of security reasons. So give relative path to your css and then intercept the request.

I would suggest using a pattern to differentiate b/w actual relative and custom relative paths. e.g. use `android_asset/my_css_file.css` instead of `my_css_file.css` and modify `shouldInterceptRequest()` accordingly to always intercept requests starting from `android_asset`.

Comment: using the code u mentioned and replacing href=\"file:///android_asset/my_css_file.css\" with href=\"my_css_file.css\" did the trick .. thnx