# How can I refer a font file in res/fonts from a css file in assets folder?

Tags: android

I want to configure a webview with a custom font from my res/font folder, How can I configure the css located in assets folder to use it?

Comment: Please, post `CSS` example

Comment: Possible Duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31516518/how-to-load-android-assets-css-files-to-android-webview-url

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to configure the WebView . You just reference the css in your index.html file in both are assets folder.