# Webview not loading css in android device folder

Tags: java, android, arrays, kotlin, webview

On my app, user can download a book.

It gets stored in:

```
data/data/com.app.app/download/publications/unzipped/Downloaded Book
```

Inside that Downloaded Book folder, there is "`main.css`" and "`style.css`" and "`page.html`"

Now in webview I want to load like this:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/",
            """ 
<!DOCTYPE html>        
<html>
<head>
$joinedCss
</head>
<body> 
  $htmlPage
</body>
$jQuery
$js
</html>""", "text/html", "UTF-8", null)
```

Where **$JoinedCss** is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/data/data/com.app.app/download/publications/unzipped/Downloaded Book/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/data/data/com.app.app/download/publications/unzipped/Downloaded Book/style.css"">
```

Where **$htmlPage** is:

```
<div> some stuffs </div>
```

Where **$jQuery** and **$js** is:

```
var jQuery = "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"js/jquery.min.1.7.js\"></script>"
var js = "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"js/lfn.js\"></script>"
```

The html loads, but the css not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding those files to your assets folder and updating the href location as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31516796/11644123). To create/add assets folder see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302603/where-to-place-the-assets-folder-in-android-studio#27673773).